# SQL Percent of a row that is not null

Tags: sql, sum

I have a row which shows charter trips copilots, not every charter trip has a copliot.

Im having difficulty figuring out how to go about this.

I imagine I would have to get the count of the values in that row that are not null(meaning that there is a copliot) and then divide it by the total. Im not sure how to divide it, How would i get the number of the total lines in that row. I could hardcode it but that wouldnt help if more data gets entered into the database.

Is there a way to just count the number of columns that are in that row?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In standard SQL, you can do:

```
select (100.0*count(copilot))/count(*)
from t
```

In SQL, the expression `count(copilot)` counts the number of values that are not NULL.  The expression `count(*)` is the total number of rows.

In some versions of SQL, dividing two integers produces an integer.  So, 1/2 = 0, not 0.5.  To ensure non-integer division, the "100" is phrased as a non-integer constant rather than `100`.

Comment: Thank You,How would i go about formatting the number to 2 decimal places?

Comment: @user214577 . . . The simplest way is to cast to a fixed numeric type, such as `select cast(100.0*count(copliot))/count(*) as decimal(6, 2))`.

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(copilot is not null)*100/count(*) as copilot_percent
from charters
```

Your question seems to suggest that there are multiple copilot columns in the table. First of all, that suggests poor DB design -- you should normalize the DB by moving them into their own dependent table. But in this design, you would do:

```
select count(copilot1 is not null and copilot2 is not null and copilot3 is not null ...)*100/count(*) as copilot_percent
from charters;
```