# Is there a way to find unique count of values and null percent for all columns in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to find the unique count and null percent for all columns in a mysql database for the purpose of data discovery(tables with approximation of null/distinct is also fine). Postgres has the pg_stats table with the null_frac and n_distinct fields, is there a table containing similar stats in mysql? Not looking to run this query through all the columns.

```
SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT col1) FROM table1;
```

Here is a sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE employees (
  employeeNumber INT NOT NULL,
  lastName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  firstName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  extension VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  email VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  officeCode VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  reportsTo INT DEFAULT NULL,
  jobTitle VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (employeeNumber)
) ;

INSERT  INTO employees(employeeNumber,lastName,firstName,extension,email,officeCode,reportsTo,jobTitle) VALUES
(1002,'Murphy','Diane','x5800','dmurphy@classicmodelcars.com','1',NULL,'President'),
(1056,'Patterson','Mary','x4611','mpatterso@classicmodelcars.com','1',1002,'VP Sales'),
(1076,'Firrelli','Jeff','x9273','jfirrelli@classicmodelcars.com','1',1002,'VP Marketing'),
(1088,'Patterson','William','x4871','wpatterson@classicmodelcars.com','6',1056,'Sales Manager (APAC)'),
(1102,'Bondur','Gerard','x5408','gbondur@classicmodelcars.com','4',1056,'Sale Manager (EMEA)'),
(1143,'Bow','Anthony','x5428','abow@classicmodelcars.com','1',1056,'Sales Manager (NA)'),
(1165,'Jennings','Leslie','x3291','ljennings@classicmodelcars.com','1',1143,'Sales Rep'),
(1166,'Thompson','Leslie','x4065','lthompson@classicmodelcars.com','1',1143,'Sales Rep'),
(1188,'Firrelli','Julie','x2173','jfirrelli@classicmodelcars.com','2',1143,'Sales Rep'),
(1216,'Patterson','Steve','x4334','spatterson@classicmodelcars.com','2',1143,'Sales Rep'),
(1286,'Tseng','Foon Yue','x2248','ftseng@classicmodelcars.com','3',1143,'Sales Rep'),
(1323,'Vanauf','George','x4102','gvanauf@classicmodelcars.com','3',1143,'Sales Rep'),
(1337,'Bondur','Loui','x6493','lbondur@classicmodelcars.com','4',1102,'Sales Rep'),
(1370,'Hernandez','Gerard','x2028','ghernande@classicmodelcars.com','4',1102,'Sales Rep'),
(1401,'Castillo','Pamela','x2759','pcastillo@classicmodelcars.com','4',1102,'Sales Rep'),
(1501,'Bott','Larry','x2311','lbott@classicmodelcars.com','7',1102,'Sales Rep'),
(1504,'Jones','Barry','x102','bjones@classicmodelcars.com','7',1102,'Sales Rep'),
(1611,'Fixter','Andy','x101','afixter@classicmodelcars.com','6',1088,'Sales Rep'),
(1612,'Marsh','Peter','x102','pmarsh@classicmodelcars.com','6',1088,'Sales Rep'),
(1619,'King','Tom','x103','tking@classicmodelcars.com','6',1088,'Sales Rep'),
(1621,'Nishi','Mami','x101','mnishi@classicmodelcars.com','5',1056,'Sales Rep'),
(1625,'Kato','Yoshimi','x102','ykato@classicmodelcars.com','5',1621,'Sales Rep'),
(1702,'Gerard','Martin','x2312','mgerard@classicmodelcars.com','4',1102,'Sales Rep');
```

This the expected output able to get from postgres using the pg_stats table(specifically the num_null and num_of_distinct columns)
[image: expected output screenshot]
Sample table structure and data in postgres: https://pastebin.com/fXg3RJdi

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Percent of a row that is not null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16123012/sql-percent-of-a-row-that-is-not-null)

Comment: Hi, sorry it does not really apply since I am not looking to run the select count distinct, I am looking for a metadata table that might contain such information, similar to the pg_stat table from postgres.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69624253/edit), post a sample of data and/or table structure and the equivalent Postgres solution that you're looking for (an expected output). I'm guessing that this can be done with a `prepared statement` over `information_schema` database but need some data sample to work with.

Comment: @FaNo_FN Hi, I just added screenshots for the sample data and output from postgres, the table structure is not much of an issue, looking for some table (probably actually in the information_schema containing such information)

Comment: Can you post them in tabular/textual format? Especially the sample data? I'm trying to recreate the scenario but it's not easy to re-write (recreate the table & data sample) from an image. Besides, for data sample and/or codes, tabular/textual form is much preferred on stack overflow. Thanks.

Comment: @FaNo_FN Thanks for the advice, I have added a pastebin link to the sample table structure and data in postgres, you may run them to create the table insert the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own procedure that will build such a report using prepared statements.

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE sys_column_stats (IN tableName varchar(64))
BEGIN

  SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;

  SELECT 
    GROUP_CONCAT(
      'SELECT \'', c.column_name,'\' AS column_name,',
      '(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `', c.column_name,'`) FROM `', table_name, '`) AS distinct_count,', 
      '(SELECT SUM(`', c.column_name,'` IS NULL) FROM `', table_name, '`) AS null_count'
      -- ... More stats you need
      SEPARATOR ' UNION ALL '
    ) AS sql_statement
  INTO @sql
  FROM information_schema.columns c
  WHERE `table_name` = tableName;
    
  PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
  EXECUTE stmt; 
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END//

DELIMITER ;
```

Usage:

```
CALL sys_column_stats('employees');
```

The SQL statement in the procedure prepares the `UNION ALL` query as

```
SELECT
    'email' AS column_name,
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `email`) FROM `employees`) AS distinct_count,
    (SELECT SUM(`email` IS NULL) FROM `employees`) AS null_count
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    'employeeNumber' AS column_name,
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `employeeNumber`) FROM `employees`) AS distinct_count,
    (SELECT SUM(`employeeNumber` IS NULL)FROM `employees`) AS null_count
UNION ALL
[ ... ]
```

[fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dRXfiFB6H6DDUT4iAGn46y/0)

Answer (score 0):

This idea is using prepared statement.

1. Setting up base query:

```
SET @sql1 := (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('SELECT "',column_name,'" AS column_name, 
COUNT(DISTINCT ',column_name,') AS num_of_distinct,
SUM(CASE WHEN ',column_name,' IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS num_null,
COUNT(*) AS TotalRows
FROM employees ') SEPARATOR ' 
UNION ALL
') 
FROM information_schema.COLUMNS 
WHERE table_name='employees'
AND table_schema= 'public');

/*Check @sql1 variable*/
SELECT @sql1;
```

2. Setting up outer query with percentage calculation:

```
SET @sql2 := CONCAT('SELECT *, CAST(num_null/TotalRows AS DECIMAL(14,7)) perc_of_null, 
ROUND((num_of_distinct/TotalRows)*100,2) perc_of_distinct
FROM (',@sql1,') tv;');

/*Check @sql2 variable*/
SELECT @sql2;
```

3. Preparing statement from `@sql2` variable, execute then deallocate it:

```
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql2;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Result:

| column_name | num_of_distinct | num_null | TotalRows | perc_of_null | perc_of_distinct |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| employeeNumber | 23 | 0 | 23 | 0.0000000 | 100.00 |
| lastName | 19 | 0 | 23 | 0.0000000 | 82.61 |
| firstName | 21 | 0 | 23 | 0.0000000 | 91.30 |
| extension | 20 | 0 | 23 | 0.0000000 | 86.96 |
| email | 22 | 0 | 23 | 0.0000000 | 95.65 |
| officeCode | 7 | 0 | 23 | 0.0000000 | 30.43 |
| reportsTo | 6 | 1 | 23 | 0.0434783 | 26.09 |
| jobTitle | 7 | 0 | 23 | 0.0000000 | 30.43 |

Here's a [demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=011c8747bc3df4a1b7a9763e46f3ae6f).

For the full result that is according to your screenshot, you probably can modify the `@sql2` variable as following:

```
SET @sql2 := CONCAT('SELECT CONCAT(tt.table_schema,".",tt.table_name),
       cc.COLUMN_NAME,
       cc.COLUMN_TYPE,
       cc.IS_NULLABLE,
       cc.COLUMN_KEY,
       tt.TABLE_COMMENT,
       cc.EXTRA,
       num_of_distinct,
       num_null,
       num_null/TotalRows perc_of_null, ROUND((num_of_distinct/TotalRows)*100,2) perc_of_distinct
FROM information_schema.COLUMNS cc 
  JOIN information_schema.TABLES tt ON cc.TABLE_SCHEMA=tt.TABLE_SCHEMA AND cc.TABLE_NAME=tt.TABLE_NAME 
JOIN (',@sql1,') tv ON cc.COLUMN_NAME=tv.column_name  
WHERE tt.table_schema="Public" AND tt.table_name="employees";');
```

However, I'm not entirely sure if the table attributes on MySQL matches the ones from Postgres.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for this detailed solution. Just wondering how is this statement's speed comparing to run SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT *) iteratively on all the columns(i.e. through python to get all the columns first and then run the SQL)? This prepared statements looks like it runs the COUNT(DISTINCT) on all columns and then UNION them.

Comment: I think, if you're able to construct a single query without `UNION ALL`, then it's probably much faster. The reason why I use union is simply because your expected result (on the image of postgres example) shows it like that. If you're ok with the results of each column separated by columns instead of rows, then probably it's possible to construct a single query. If you have an idea of how the expected output for that, can you update your question and include it? Thanks

Comment: Also, how these columns be displayed `num_null, TotalRows, perc_of_null, perc_of_distinct` if we're going to do single query approach?